# How to turn off Facebook tab notification on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

Facebook tab on Google Chrome shows a number, which usually corresponds to the number of unread notifications. Here is an example:

[image]

Is there any way that this can be turned off so it only displays the website name and nothing else? I can see I have turned off notifications from Facebook on my Chrome browser but the number icon does not go away. I know other websites like YouTube has a similar feature, but those ones are not as important to me as much as Facebook is. Ideally, if it can be turned off for all the websites, then it would be great. If not, I hope there is at least a way to turn it off for Facebook. I have looked up a bit, but no solutions have been helpful yet.

I do have the latest version of Google Chrome. Please let me know if you require more information.

Comment: Having the same problem. Following your question.

Comment: I don't know if Google Chrome has also the concept of Tab Stacks, but I am currently using the Vivaldi Browser and  found a work around for the problem. Not that it will completely hide the n. of notifications, but as the Facebook tab is in a 2. level of the tab list, it will not annoy me grabbing my attention with that irritating number on the 1. level of the tab list.

Comment: I think I discovered a solution for this. It needs a very little bit of programming. I made it for Vivaldi, which supports user scripts natively. I think Chrome also supports them via `greasemonkey` or `tampermonkey` extensions. It is posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908925/userscript-for-getting-rid-of-annoying-notifications-counter-on-title-of-pages-l